# Using Trigger to get ID on Insert - SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, triggers

I have a table (table_a) that, upon insert, needs to retrieve the next available id from the available_id field in another table (table_b) to use as the primary key in table_a, and then increment the available_id field in table_b by 1. While doing this via stored procedures is easy, I need to be able to have this occur on any insert into the table.

I know I need to use triggers, but I am unsure how to code this. Any advice?

Basically this is my dilema:
I need to ensure 2 different tables have unique id's throughout. What would be the best way to do this without using GUID's? (Some of this code cannot be controlled on our end and requires ints as id's).

Comment: Why are you getting ids that way? This is a poor practice that can have serios concurrency issues.

Comment: What HLGEM said - you should really use an IDENTITY column: http://sqlservernation.com/blogs/tipweek/archive/2009/02/23/identity-columns.aspx

Comment: The tables do have an IDENTITY column, this is a separate primary key that is used because 2 tables (table_a and table_c) get unioned together. This is an attempt to ensure these id's (separate from the IDENTITY--sorry, confusing) do not overlap. Table c will need to have this same "trigger" attached.

Comment: If the id values mean nothing then why not just have one table that starts at 1 and another that starts at 1 billion?  Unless you are going to create more than a billion of these rows, you will have no collisions.

Comment: I have no way of knowing that 1 billion will never be reached. Though it would be unlikely, there is technically no limit to how many inserts there could be.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is DON'T! Use an identity field instead.

In the first place, inserts can have multiple records and so a trigger to properly do this would have to account for that making it rather tricky to write. It would have to be an instead of trigger which is also tricky as you wouldn't have one of the required values (I assume your ID field is required) in the initial insert. In the second place two inserts going on at the same time could try to pick the same number or could lock the second connection for a good bit of time if you are doing a large import of data in one connection.

Comment: +1: ..and isolation levels could allow for reading before the update, causing a unique and/or primary key error

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Oracle-style sequence, described here, calling it either via a trigger or from your application (providing the resulting value to your insert routine):

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/custom-auto-generated-sequences-with-sql-server

He mentions these issues to consider:

•  What if two processes attempt to add
   a row to the table at the exact same
   time? Can you ensure that the same
   value is not generated for both
   processes?

•  There can be overhead querying the
   existing data each time you'd like to
   insert new data

•  Unless this is implemented as a
   trigger, this means that all inserts
   to your data must always go through
   the same stored procedure that
   calculates these sequences. This
   means that bulk imports, or moving
   data from production to testing and
   so on, might not be possible or might
   be very inefficient.

•  If it is implemented as a trigger,
   will it work for a set-based
   multi-row INSERT statement? If so,
   how efficient will it be? This
   function wouldn't work if called for
   each row in a single set-based INSERT
   -- each NextCustomerNumber() returned would be the same value.